# Python: Extracting data values from a website

Tags: python, string, byte

What's the simplest way of getting data values from a website so that I can use them?
So we have a simple way of getting the page source data by doing:

```
usock = urllib2.urlopen("WEBSITE URL")
data = usock.read()
usock.close()
print data
```

Within that page data that we grabbed and printed, there are two lines that we're interested in.

```
<input type="hidden" name="SECRETCODE" value="l53DLeOfj1" />
<input type="hidden" name="NotSoSecretCode" value="Nr4MNjyK" />
```

If I knew what the names of the values are that I'm looking for, what would be the best way of getting the values so that I could put them in my own variables and further play around with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup) will be the easiest solution for your need.

```
html = '''
<input type="hidden" name="SECRETCODE" value="l53DLeOfj1" />
<input type="hidden" name="NotSoSecretCode" value="Nr4MNjyK" />
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.find("input", {"name":"SECRETCODE"})
print soup.find("input", {"name":"NotSoSecretCode"})
```

You may want to use cumbersome regex for this purpose as well if you have lot of times in your hand!!

Answer (score 0):

[lxml](http://lxml.de/) is the most powerful tool for extracting the data from xml/html files. Based on [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use pyparsing then

```
from pyparsing import  Literal, Suppress, removeQuotes, dblQuotedString

def cleanQuotedString(name):
    return dblQuotedString.setParseAction(removeQuotes).setResultsName(name)

def extractTokens(inputStream):
    head = Suppress(Literal('<input'))
    tail = Suppress(Literal('/>'))
    equalSign = Suppress(Literal('='))
    typekey = Suppress(Literal('type')) + equalSign + cleanQuotedString('type')
    namekey = Suppress(Literal('name')) + equalSign + cleanQuotedString('name')
    valueKey = Suppress(Literal('value')) + equalSign + cleanQuotedString('value')

    grammar = head + typekey + namekey + valueKey + tail

    return grammar.scanString(inputStream)

usock = urllib2.urlopen("WEBSITE URL")
tokens = extractTokens(usock.read())
usock.close()
for item, _, _ in tokens:
    print("Element with type =", item.type, ", name = ", item.name, ", value = ", item.value)
```